# Duplicate topics in the documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation

There are two Documentation topics related to one [pdo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdo) tag:

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/pdo/topics
and
https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/5828/pdo

The former one being advertised on the sidebar, but essentially bogus.
The latter one is alive but it  seems nowhere is linked to the original tag.

What can be done in such a situation? And what to do in general with top-level topics which actually are subordinates to another topic (PDO is a subordinate for PHP here).

Comment: If PDO is a big enough topic, you should move the content from [php] to [pdo] and link to it from [php]. Otherwise, ask an employee of SO to merge the two so [php] will show up in the sidebar of the [tag:pdo] page.

Comment: It's apparently not that big. So, what is the procedure for asking an SO employee?

Comment: I’d say to go to [the Docs chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117558/documentation-public-beta) and ping an employee who’s there.